# Menu in default application aka CRS is not showing up in ATG

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, atg, oracle-commerce

I'm trying hands on the default application aka *CRS (CommerceReferenceStore)* which is deployed when ATG is configured. In my case, I've integrated the ATG 11.0.0 with Endeca. Now I'm facing two problems.

 
 **1.**  When I restart my system then I always have to do the indexing all over again. Is it good to go or is there some problem what I am doing?

 **2.**  Another, Whenever I do it *i.e. Indexing* menu isn't showing up in the CRS application. It started from last 3-4 times. And I don't know why is it happeing even if I'm doing it (indexing) in the same way as I was doing earlier?

**Please guide me through and tell me if I'm doing something wrong**

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: Do you lose your index when you restart your system or when you restart Endeca services? What do you mean by Indexing menu in the CRS application, could you be more specific? Lastly, what steps are you following to perform your Baseline index?

Comment: Firstly I start the *Production Server*.
Then I cross check the services all four.
Then I hit *ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin* nucleus and start the *Baseline Index*.
**But this ends up like I said CRS application without any menu.**

Answer (score 0):

You have to run promoteContent.bat/sh from the control folder of your Endeca App folder after running the base line index. If you don't do so, then your indexed data will be still in the A-graph port and not on D-Graph. CRS will be pulling data only from D-Graph port hence you still wont be able to see the items on CRS.

Comment: Are you confusing A-Graph with Authoring Dgraph? Two significantly different concepts.